# Docker SDK: Can't get accurate number of containers on Worker node from Leader node

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-swarm

I have a swarm with three Managers and one Worker. I also have a monitor_service that tries to use the Docker SDK for Python to get the actual number of containers in a tracked_service. This tracked_service lives on the Worker node.

If I was dealing with a service not on a swarm, I would get the accurate number of containers in that service with the following docker SDK method:

```
dockerClient = docker.from_env()
containers = dockerClient.containers.list(filters={"name": tracked_service_stack_prefix})
containerCount = len(containers)
```

On a swarm, however, the above code results in a containerCount of 0. I assume this is because the Docker SDK can only perform container methods on the Leader node, and ignores all other nodes in a swarm. Because my target_service is on the Worker node, I cannot find out its container count.

Is this any way I can get the number of containers in a service that lies on a non-Leader node?

Side-note: I am not talking about the service replica or task counts. I found that these numbers are only the desired number of containers-- not the ACTUAL count. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in the Low-Level Docker API (https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html):

```
apiClient = docker.APIClient()
tasks = apiClient.tasks(filters={"name": 'target_service_stack_prefix', "desired-state": 'running'})
... # Apply any additional, not built-in filters by parsing the resulting list.
```